# Failed to include jquery 1.9.1 library

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, netbeans

I have download jquery-1.9.1 library, then I created a folder in NetBeans, called it "js" and used the src attribute:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js">
```

The problem is that if I include jquery some content of the page doesn't get included, which makes me think that the library is not properly included.

This is the full javascript code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js">
        function write()
        {
            var loc= document.getElementById("purchase");
            var sep= location.href.indexOf("item=");
            var item=parseInt(location.href.substring(sep+5,location.href.length));
            switch(item)
            {
                case 1:
                    string= "Opere orchestrali vol. 1";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    string= "Concerti per pianoforte n.1,n.4";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    string= "Concerto di Capodanno 2013";
                    break;
                case 4:
                    string= "Viva Verdi. Ouvertures &amp; Preludes";
                    break;
                case 5:
                    string= "Jaywalkin";
                    break;
                case 6:
                    string= "The Real Life  ";
                    break;
                case 7:
                    string= "Shango";
                    break;
                case 8:
                    string= "Complete Soul";
                    break;
                case 9:
                    string= "Old Yellow Moon";
                    break;
                case 10:
                    string= "In Time";
                    break;
                case 11:
                    string= "Greatest Country Love Songs";
                    break;
                case 12:
                    string= "Spring Break... here to Party";
                    break;
            }
            if(string !== undefined)
            {
                loc.innerHTML= "Acquisto effettuato: " + string;
            }
        }
    </script>
```

The behavior is very simple: it just reads a get parameter named "item", and according to it's value (from 1 to 12) it puts the title of a disc inside a html tag.

If I don't include jquery it works perfecly, if I include jquery it doesn't work, and it doesn't put anything inside the tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to close the `<script>` tag for the linked jQuery library and then add the rest of the JavaScript in a seperate set of tags. For example.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
--------------------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^

<script>
   //The rest of your code
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not closed the script tag

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js">
```

Change it to this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
```

Note you can't add the js code between the another js file is included.
It should be

```
<script>
...
...
...
</script>
```